# VB6 regex for matching a date needs tweaking

Tags: regex, vb6

I'm trying to use VB6 regex with capture groups to parse and rearrange a string:

```
Dim innfilename As String
Dim outfilename As String
innfilename = "4.6.12.Jack&DianeWedding004.jpg"
outfilename = innfilename

Dim regexB As RegExp
Dim regexBMatchCol As MatchCollection
Dim regexBMatch As Match
Set regexB = New RegExp
regexB.IgnoreCase = True
regexB.Global = True
regexB.Pattern = "^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2,4})\.(.*)$"
Set regexBMatchCol = regexB.Execute(innfilename)

If regexBMatchCol.Count > 0 Then
    Set regexBMatch = regexBMatchCol(0)
    mnth = regexBMatch.SubMatches(0)
    dayy = regexBMatch.SubMatches(1)
    year = regexBMatch.SubMatches(2)
    remd = regexBMatch.SubMatches(3)
    yearInt = Val(year)
    mnthInt = Val(mnth)
    dayyInt = Val(dayy)
    If yearInt >= 70 And yearInt <= 99 Then
        year = "19" & year
    Else
        year = "20" & year
    End If
    If mnthInt >= 1 And mnthInt <= 9 Then
        mnth = "0" & mnth
    End If
    If dayyInt >= 1 And dayyInt <= 9 Then
        dayy = "0" & dayy
    End If
    outfilename = year & "." & mnth & "." & dayy & "." & remd
End If
```

but my regex isn't working i.e.  regexBMatchCol.Count winds up being zero .
Can anybody spot my error?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: In VB6 if I wanted to make a string that was just a backslash, would I need to escape them via `"\\"` or would `"\"` work? If the former, then the backslashes in your regex need to be escaped for VB6.

Comment: That looks like it should work - which Regex library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a date using regex with MM.DD.YYYY pattern, then use this:

```
regexB.Pattern = "(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2,4})"
```